# Tkinter GUI Python background color

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter

I'm writing a Tkinter application with buttons, graphs, sliders, etc, but I can't get their background color to be uniform.

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('Button')
root.configure(bg='gray')

Button(text='Button', bg='gray').pack(side=BOTTOM)
root.mainloop()
```

If you run this code, the background of the main window is indeed gray, but the image of the button has a white area around it. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: does `borderwidth=0` help at all?

Comment: I'm not sure what is causing your issue, because when I execute the code myself I don't get any "white area" around the button. I get a bit of white on the top and left, but that's due to the relief setting of the button.

Comment: Wow, looking back at old posts and seeing people import the same thing twice in 1 script

Answer (score 2):

If the issue is that you don't like the default button effect on your system, you don't have to change the border width; instead you can set `relief='flat'` in the button declaration. That way, you'll still get the "sunken" look when you click the button, which you won't get if you just set `borderwidth` to 0 or a value close to it. Another issue with lessening `borderwidth` is that it may make the button smaller than expected.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on mgilson's comment, I tried using borderwidth=.001 and as far as I could tell it 'effectively' removed the border on your button. Hope this helps!

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
root =Tk()
root.title('Button')
root.configure(bg='gray')

Button(text='Button',bg='gray',borderwidth=.001).pack(side=BOTTOM)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Now that I look into it more, `borderwidth=.1` works equally well

Comment: In addition, if you are in interested in keeping the button gray when you push it, you can use `backgroundactive='gray'`.

Comment: Unless there is some difference in the version of Tk we are using, I definitely get a sunken effect for both alternatives here. I can see a 1-2 pixel change in the size of the button making a difference if you are trying to make callbacks based on coordinates, but I doubt you'll notice any visual difference.

Comment: I see, using just `relief='flat'` still gives you a border around the sunken part.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing sounds like the result of `highlightthickness` being set to a non-zero value (which is the default). You might try setting it to zero, or setting `highlightbackground` to your background color.